# How to download sources for xcode simulator

Tags: codenameone

For app distribution to app store, we need to make couple (well, lots of them) of screenshots from all types of apple devices. In native app, we do it through simulator. How can we do it with codename one? How can I download the sources required for xcode simulator? Or is there any other way, how this can this be achieved (instead of buying all types of apple devices there are of course) ?

Comment: James answer is probably the best answer as we don't need this as much. Notice that you can generate a screenshot from the Codename One simulators too and install additional skins using the "more..." menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple now lets you upload one image size and they will scale it for the rest. I don't recall which size, but probably the 6plus. They tell you on iTunes Connect where you create the app details. You can use the CN1 simulator to capture screenshots. Set the skin to the desired device type and press F2 to capture the screen. The screen capture will just be what is displayed on screen, but there are some tools out there to give it the look of a real device. See this blog post:

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/3-image-tools-for-app-marketing.html